# Given that $f$ is differentiable on $[0, 2]$, finding $c$ in the interval such that $f'(c) = 1/2$

Tags: real-analysis

If $f: [0, 2]  \to \mathbb{R} $ is a differentiable function such that $f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1, f(2) = 0$, show that there is a $c \in [0, 2]$ such that $f'(c) = 1/2$.

I'm stumped on this problem. My intuition is to use the Mean Value theorem in some way, but the definition of the function does not seem conducive to picking an $f(a)$ and an $f(b)$ such that $c$ could ever be equal to $1/2$. What am I missing here?

Comment: I think you can use the Mean Value theorem separately on the intervals $[0,1]$ and $[1,2]$, and then use [Darboux's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)).

Comment: Thanks so much, that makes sense! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, there doesn't *need* to be such a $c$ on the interval. You can disprove this by taking $f(x) = x$, which has the derivative $f'(x)=1$ for all $x$.

It is differentiable and satisfies the same conditions as your $x$ given to us. However, the derivative is never $1/2$.

My intuition is that there's something wrong in the problem - either there's information you overlooked, or there's a typo. (I originally read $f(c)$ and not $f'(c)$ and was about to suggest the intermediate value theorem, but I caught myself. That would be a potential typo example.)

Comment: IMO, this should be a comment, since its pretty obvious there's some missing info in the question.

Comment: I did have a typo in the question, which I changed just now (sorry about that!). $f(2) = 0$ in this problem, and I had originally written $f(2) = 2$. Though the $f'(c)$ isn't a typo, and the rest of the question is as written.

Answer (score 0):

Since the derivatives possess intermediate value property if $f'(x) \neq 1/2$ for all $x\in [0,2]$ then we have either $f'(x) >1/2$ on $[0,2]$ or $f'(x) <1/2$ on whole of $[0,2]$. For the first case this means that $f$ is strictly increasing in $[0,2]$ and this contradicts $f(0)=f(2)=0$.

For the second case note that $g(x) =f(x) - x/2$ is strictly decreasing in $[0,2]$ and this contradicts $g(0)=0,g(1)=1/2$.